# What is the proper way to stop/kill a .net core web app process after launching a process to display the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

When creating a .NET Core Web app C# and debugging you can opt to Launch the browser when Running the app.  The console launches and then the url launches in your preferred browser.  Once you close the browser tab opened by the debug session, the app process it stop and is no longer running on the machine.

When I published the app, the page does not launch automatically so I am starting a new Process to do so.  I've added an event handler to the process before starting it but the since the app didn't launch the process it doesn't receive any notification when the tab has been closed.

What is the proper way to go about launching your .NET Core web app and/or handle communicating between the two?

I even tried adding a Close button but JS won't allow me to close the window as I haven't opened it.

I'm creating my Process as follows:

```
var p = Process.Start("cmd", "/C start http://localhost:5000");
```

I've tried

```
p.WaitForExit();
p.EventHandler += newHandler;
```

and I also tried using ProcessStartInfo but the only thing that is working right now is if I set a Timer and then kill the process when the timer is activated but this doesn't seem too clean.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: there is no "proper" way as this is not even remotely usual.  your web app runs on a web server normally,  and all the client browsers run remotely and independently

Comment: Thanks for your input @KeithNicholas.  I have done what I am asking using NancyFX where you can self host and I was hoping I would be able to use .net core self host using Kestrel and make it work "like NancyFX" but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow-up with the process I feel is the most graceful way that I am happy with.

A few pieces of info that may be helpful in creating your own process.  It was a goal of mine to use .net core to self host a client side web app which communicates with a server hosted web api.

- I am using Razor views and .net core 3.1
- I am using Startup and utilizing applicationLifeTime to handle OnStartup where I start the process as I described in my original post.

At this point the web app opens and if the user decides to close the browser the process doesn't know and continues to run in the background.

In order to prevent it from continuing to run and allow the user to initiate it closing, I made a few the following additions.

First, I added a timer that uses a configurable length of time via appsettings.  When starting the process that opens the browser I call and set the timer that will perform an "AutoShutdown" if the process is still running after the configurable length of time that I defaulted to 1hr.  I am using Enviroment.Exit(0) in the event that handles closing the running process.

My View is using a Model that contains a property who's value will be set from the page via a hidden field.
I added a Close button to the View that is displayed to the user at startup.  When the user clicks close, I use jquery to set a hidden field in the view and then I use jquery to submit the form.

When the Model is received, the value set by the client's request to close is true and you can handle the close without display errors if you use a Timer and Start it almost immediately after redirecting the View to a view with a message to the client.  Whether they leave it open or close it, the process will have closed.  Example of how I did it below.

Finally, in Main.cs I put a check in to check if there is an existing process running and close it before starting a new one.  I added this because the client may not always close the browser and/or they may attempt to start it before the "AutoShutdown" timer has kicked in.

This is more "hacky" then I would like but I couldn't find anything else that didn't throw and show Bad Request when trying to use Envirnoment.Exit(0) when the client is still has the view open and I was unsuccessful at being able to allow console input so that I could send close to the console.

This is how I am handling the close request from the client in my Controller

```
if (ui.HandleCloseApp)
            {
                
                var app = Process.GetProcessesByName("NameOfYourWebApp");
        
                if (app.Length >= 1)
                {
                    foreach (var p in app)
                    {
                        if (p.ProcessName == "NameOfYourWebApp")
                        {
                             
                            p.Close();
                            p.Dispose();                           
                     
                        }
                    }
                }
                var t = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
                t.Elapsed += OnClose;
                t.Start();
                return View("Close");
   
            }
```

I hope this helps someone else in creating their own "graceful" process that shouldn't be :)

I'm still open if anyone has input to share.  Thx!